# How to remove Javascript plugin code in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, json, wordpress

My wordpress website installed `Social Plugin` to share post.

When i get `JSON` from website , that plugin `javascript` codes are including in my text like following.

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=226488567527811";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));
```

I want to show text in `UITextView` without these code.

How can i remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only trying to search and remove that piece of code from the text, here is a snipper for you:

```
- (NSString *) removeSubstring:(NSString *)fromString thatStartsWith:(NSString *)startsWith andEndsWith:(NSString *)endsWith
{

    NSArray *splitByStartsWith = [fromString componentsSeparatedByString:startsWith];
    if ([splitByStartsWith count] > 1) {
        NSArray *splitByEndsWith = [splitByStartsWith[1] componentsSeparatedByString:endsWith];
        if ([splitByEndsWith count] > 1) {
            NSString *replaceThis = [startsWith stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",splitByEndsWith[0],endsWith];
            return [fromString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:replaceThis withString:@""];
        }
    }
    return fromString;
}
```

Then you can call it like this ...

```
NSString *removedString = [yourObjectThatHasThatCodeAbove removeSubstring:stringDataThatYouGotFromServer thatStartsWith:@"(function(" andEndsWith:@"facebook-jssdk\"));"]);
```

It will return the removed version of your string.